# Creating "Left-Aligned" and "Right-Aligned" HorizontalScrollViews/Recyclerviews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

This is my first post here, so please let me know if I should rephrase my question in any way!

I have been tasked with creating a UI to test something, and my requirements are that the user can navigate the entire app using all directional swipes (up, down, left, right). I am fairly new to creating Android applications, so advice coming from any level of skill would be useful. Even if you think I should be designing it differently, I would still like to learn to implement it this way, as a learning experience.

Currently, I have created a scrollable tab layout, where each tab contains a fragment. The goal is for each of these fragments to be vertically scrollable, and contain either horizontal RecyclerViews or HorizontalScrollViews at even intervals as you scroll down the fragment.

To start, I cannot get vertical scrolling to work together with horizontal scrolling at the same time - whether that is using RecyclerViews or ScrollViews or something else. My tabs do work fine and seem to work together with the HorizontalScrollView without any problems.

But even more importantly, I am attempting to make "left-aligned" and "right-aligned" HorizontalScrollViews (or RecyclerViews), where they each start a certain distance away from their respective side of the screen - so one would be coming out from the left side, and the next from the right of the screen. The idea is that *initially*, you can only swipe each of them in one direction (being left or right), which is made apparent to the user by how they are shown on the screen. As you scroll down, it would alternate between left-aligned and right-aligned.

So my two problems are as follows:

-I cannot get vertical scrolling to work together with horizontal scrolling, inside of a fragment of a scrollable tab view. I would be open to changing to RecyclerView or something else.

-If I create a HorizontalScrollView of buttons, I am able to make it start a certain distance from the side by changing its padding, but it does not scroll past this padding. I would like the scroll view to start a certain distance from the side of the screen, but also be able to scroll past that point (so it doesn't just disappear into the padding).

Here is my xml code for the fragment of HorizontalScrollViews. It's very simple but may give you an idea of what I mean. Of course it doesn't look very good but I'll worry about that once I get it working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:text="Credit Cards"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Card 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Card 2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Card 3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Card 4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Card 5" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:paddingRight="100dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:text="Debit Cards"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:text="Gift Cards"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:paddingRight="100dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:text="Coupons"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card 5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```